# How to scale a side of already subdivided prism?

Tags: edges, faces

How can I go from this:

[image]

To this?
[image]

How can I shrink one side of the prism and/or enlarge the other side after a subdivision?
So is there a way of proportional scaling the edges?

I didn't apply sub mod, what I mean is I just added a bunch of edges by using subdivision

Comment: Why don't you just undo subdivision, scale the prism and apply the subdivision modifier?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think you misinterpreted me, sub mod is not the matter here, it's the subdivision of faces. So yeah i can undo subdivision that, but let's say i already set all the geometry etc., it'd be inconvenient

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two solutions (at least) :

**Using proportional editing**

- Activate the option, on the bottom of the 3DView
- Choose the proportional mode (maybe linear for your case)
- Scale the face
- Eventually adjust the size of the proportional editing using the mouse wheel or <kbd>minus</kbd> / <kbd>plus</kbd> of the numeric pad

[image]

**Mesh deform**

- Add a cube (or other shape but the cube is good here)
- Edit it and make sure it bounds around totally your mesh

[image]

- For facility, make your cube appear as wire only

[image]

- Add a *mesh deform* modifier to your mesh (1, 2)
- Set the created cube above as deform object (3)
- Click '*bind*' (4)

[image]

- Now you can edit the cube, resize it the way you want, and your mesh will follow

[image]

Answer (score 13):

There are various tool that can help you in this kind of operation. Here's four that come in my mind:

- [Proportional edit:](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/proportional_edit.html)

> Proportional Edit is a way of transforming selected elements (such as
>   vertices) while having that transformation affect other nearby
>   elements

While in edit mode, enable Proportional editing with the faces to scale selected. Choose "linear" interpolation type, scale on the wanted axis and than adjust the influence radius with the mousewheel.

[image]

- [Lattice modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/lattice.html)

> A lattice consists of a three-dimensional non-renderable grid of vertices. Its main use is to give extra deformation capabilities to the underlying object it controls

While in object mode, add a Lattice object to the scene and set its' vetex number to 4. Position the lattice upon the starting mesh and scale it as it would be the obect's bounding box. Add a Lattice modifier pointing to your lattice to the objecte. Then enter in Lattice's edit mode and move the top vertices toward the center.

[image]

- [Simple deform modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/simple_deform.html) - **Taper**

> Linearly scales along Z axis.

Add the modifier to your obhect and choose Taper mode. Lock X scale (or Y) to prevent deformation on both axes and adjust other parameters on your need.

[image]

- Shear (or scale on axis) the whole face

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are few options:

1: proportional editing - press "O" or little circle between layers and snap tool. Here you can switch to "linear" mode. 
2: just remove unnecessary loops: "X" - "edge loops"
3: use "Lattice modifier"

The best option is modeling rough shape and after add details. Try avoid applying subdivision modifier always if possible. Or make back up copy of object before you apply subdivision.

Edit: I thing the best option in this case is 2. Is fast and give you better control like options 1 or 3.

Comment: I didn't apply sub mod, i meant i just added a bunch of edges by using subdivision