# Scaling an object of varied widths?

Tags: modeling, transforms

I am working on a popcorn container and was wondering if there is a way to adjust the width quickly when it is a gradual change? You could select each edge loop one by one and scale it to the needed width but is there a faster way when you have a lot of varying widths to adjust?

Is there a way to constrain the bottom edge loop and scale based on a curve graph where the top could be the most scaled and the bottom the least? Like this control graph?
[image: curve]

For example, I'd like to adjust the width of this object to the green line.

[image]

Comment: several possibilities here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57963/how-to-scale-a-side-of-already-subdivided-prism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use *Proportional Editing* with a linear falloff.  Proportional editing applies any transform you use to neighbouring vertices with some sort of interpolated falloff.

You can enable Proportional Editing by pressing <kbd>O</kbd>.  While transforming you can scroll the mouse wheel up and down to adjust the falloff distance.  You can change the falloff gradient in the footer of the 3D view, to the left of the snapping controls.

[image]